# ‘serious’ vs. ‘solemn’

Tags: british-english

[*Watching the English: The International Bestseller Revised and Updated* (2014)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444785206) by Kate Fox, [BA in Anthropology and Philosophy from Cambridge U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_Fox). p. 79

> #### HUMOUR RULES
>
> #### THE IMPORTANCE OF NOT BEING EARNEST RULE
>
> At the most basic level, an underlying rule in all English conversation is the proscription of ‘earnestness’. Although we may not have a monopoly on humour, or even on irony, the English are probably more acutely sensitive than any other nation to the distinction between **‘serious’ and ‘solemn’ [emboldening mine]**, between ‘sincerity’ and ‘earnestness’.
>          This distinction is crucial to any kind of understanding of Englishness. I cannot emphasise this strongly enough: if you are not able to grasp these subtle but vital differences, you will never understand the English – and even if you speak the language fluently, you will never feel or appear entirely at home in conversation with the English. Your English may be impeccable, but your behavioural ‘grammar’ will be full of glaring errors.
>          Once you have become sufficiently sensitised to these distinctions, the Importance of Not Being Earnest rule is really quite simple. Seriousness is acceptable; solemnity is prohibited. Sincerity is allowed; earnestness is strictly forbidden. Pomposity and self-importance are outlawed. Serious matters can be spoken of seriously, but one must never take oneself too seriously. The ability to laugh at ourselves, although it may be rooted in a form of arrogance, or at least complacency, is one of the more endearing characteristics of the English. (At least, I hope I am right about this: if I have overestimated our ability to laugh at ourselves, this book will be rather unpopular.[29])

I don't know much about England or British English. Can  a British English speaker distinguish this pair, which feels synonymous to me? I know their ordinary English definitions, but not their connotations in this context. Thanks!

Comment: To me, the thesis doesn't seem to be using the words in any different way than their dictionary definitions. There is no redefinition going on here, simply normal usage. (Interpreting or believing the passage itself is something else.)

Comment: What a wonderful passage! As an Australian (and therefore a larrikin colonial incapable of seriousness when in the presence of the British), I can attest to the very real difference between serious/sincere and solemn/earnest, the latter being a disposition commonly associated with U.S. citizens. I presume that on this issue, Canadians – like Australians – are bemused onlookers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solemn and serious can mean "grave" or "earnest", but:

- **[Serious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serious#Adjective)** can also mean "important" or "demanding careful consideration"
- **[Solemn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solemn#Adjective)** can also mean "ceremonial" or "religious" or "reverent", and implies being somewhat "gloomy".

Examples of things that are **serious**, but not necessarily solemn, are the birth of child, a graduation party, or a poker game. These occasions are important, but they are not devoid of joy or even humor. (Careful, though, as one of the additional meanings of "serious" can sometimes be "without humor")

An example of a thing that is **solemn**, but not necessarily serious, might include the 7th inauguration ceremony of a national dictator. They are conducted with great reverence and gravity, but are not really very important.

See John Cleese's commentary on the matter at ["John Cleese Explains The Difference Between Serious And Solemn"](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x16iig4)

Answer (score -1):

For me, "serious" would mean that something is genuinely very important. So I can express that something is very important or matters a lot. It doesn't really contain a lot of emotion.

"Solemn", on the other hand, carries connotations of sadness and an association with death. A funeral or the death of someone important to you is a solemn occasion: something generally to be shared privately more than socially. A solemn oath, for example that sworn to the King, would need to have a recognition of it's gravity, being unto death, so would be solemn. Bring solemn in a social situation brings the tone down and is a bit like over_sharing something that might be very private. Like grief. Something you'd prefer to keep to close family and friends.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Solemn" is often associated with death, but I don't think it's a necessary association - e.g. a coronation is solemn not because it implies the monarch's death but because it's highly ritualistic and ceremonial and humorless and ultimately really boring. Solemnity is often considered appropriate when someone dies, at least in western tradition (notwithstanding Irish wakes, etc.)

Comment: Whether grief is "Something you'd prefer to keep to close family and friends" is very much a matter of context and culture.